# How to access custom font in string array

Tags: android

I am making an array of all text in xml. I am able to change font color easily but i can't able to change  custom font  which is already exists in  assets folder. I can do this in activity but this is not my solution. I have to change lots of font in a single string array. 
If anyone have idea then plz tell me how to access the custom font from assets folder to string array xml.

Code

```
<item ><![CDATA[<font face="ai-alexia-1361531340.ttf"> <b>abcghfgvhhj</b><br/></font> ]]></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.danielespinetti.it/2013/01/custom-font-for-view.html) to set custom fonts from the XML layout.

OR

You can bundle the specific font file in your app's assets folder, and set it programmatically. Something like:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(<your TextView ID>);
Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<file name>");
tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
```

Note that you can only run this code after `setContentView()` has been called. Also, only some fonts are supported by Android, and should be in a `.ttf` (TrueType) or `.otf` (OpenType) format. Even then, some fonts may not work.

This is a [font](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Chantelli-Antiqua) that definitely works on Android, and you can use this to confirm that your code is working in case your font file isn't supported by Android.